# Multiple paths to a single route in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to have multiple urls be handled by the same route handler in sinatra:

At the moment I have:

```
get 'autocomplete' do
```

But ideally I would like:

```
get 'autocomplete_contacts', 'autocomplete_users', 'autocomplete_companies' do
```

I also need a way of getting the contacts/users/companies part out of the path if that is possible?

Can this be done in sinatra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use regexp:

```
get %r{(autocomplete_contacts|autocomplete_users|autocomplete_companies)$} do
```

Comment: good idea, here is what I ended up with:

get %r{autocomplete_(?<name>[A-Za-z]+)} do |name|

Answer (score 10):

You can simply do:

```
['autocomplete_contacts', 'autocomplete_users', 'autocomplete_companies'].each do |path|
    get path do
        # ...
    end
end
```

and then retrieve the name of the route by doing:

```
request.path_info.gsub(/^\/autocomplete_/, '')
```

inside the handler, which will yields either `contacts`, `users` or `companies`.

If you expect to route all the routes that starts with `autocomplete_` you can simply use a regex:

```
get /^autocomplete_([a-zA-Z])/ do
    # ...
end
```

and retrieve the name of the route by inspecting `params[:captures]`.

Comment: Best answer: if routes are static use an array, otherwise regex

Answer (score 5):

Use Sinatra MultiRoute Gem - it is what you need!
http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/multi_route.html

Comment: If you using namespace the multi route, then it is not working properly.  See the below link https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/issues/136